# Connecting screen to laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have quite a confusing solution and I do not understand really where the problem is actually.

I have to connect a screen that I can connect using VGA to a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. The laptop (LaptopA) has a VGA interface. The screen works perfectly through the VGA interface. So the screen is good.

I have another laptop (LaptopA) running 16.04 on which there is no VGA interface. I am using an HDMI adapter. However, when I connect the screen using the HDMI adapter, it doesn't get any signal but I've tested the HDMI adapter with another screen and it works perfectly. So the HDMI adapter is good.

Some thoughts about where the problem is not:

1. The HDMI adapter is good
2. The screen is good since it connects with LaptopA using VGA
   interface
3. It is not a problem related to HDMI driver since LaptopB works using
   the HDMI adapter with another screen

Can the problem be due to a driver problem relating to the screen ? or Something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Some monitors do not auto switch. I'm assuming by your post you meant laptop-b has no vga. If laptop-b has no vga and you are using HDMI, the HDMI plugs in directly to this laptop? And the HDMI to vga adapter is on the monitor side? 
You can try the monitor menu to see if you can switch the inputs. I have had trouble with some laptops using adapters, sometimes I have to use HDMI > dvi > vga for it to work.

You can also try to set the resolution to the lowest value on the desktop, then plug in your monitor. It could just be it doesn't support the resolution you have set currently.

Hope this helps